# Listing values in list of dictionaries

Tags: javascript

```
var dicList = [{
  student_id: 334,
  full_name: "student B",
  score: 9,
  class_id: 222
}, {
  student_id: 333,
  full_name: "student A",
  score: 7,
  class_id: 222
}]

for (var i = 0; i++; i < dicList.length) {
  for (var key in dicList[i]) {
    if (test.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key, dicList[i][key]);
    }
  }
}
```

currently returns undefined, I want it to return a list of the values for each attribute in each dictionary

Comment: Please post the expected output. What is `test` in your code?

Comment: Your for loop arguments are in the wrong order, and what's `test`?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i++; i < dicList.length)` change it to `for (var i = 0; i < dicList.length; i++;)`. And replace `test` with `docList[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- swich the last two parts, *`condition`* and *`final-expression`* part of the [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), and

  ```
  for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
      statement
  ```
- check `dicList[1]` instead of `test`.

```js
var dicList = [{ student_id: 334, full_name: "student B", score: 9, class_id: 222 }, { student_id: 333, full_name: "student A", score: 7, class_id: 222 }]

for (var i = 0; i < dicList.length; i++) {     // move i++ to the end
    for (var key in dicList[i]) {
        if (dicList[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {  // use dicList[i] instead of test
            console.log(key, dicList[i][key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could also add that the `if` statement is kind of useless, as the `for(var key in...` won't ever loop through something that is not a key of the current object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and `forEach()` iterate through result array.

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(f){
  return [].concat(...this.map(f))
}
var dicList = [{student_id: 334,  full_name: "student B",  score: 9,  class_id: 222}, {  student_id: 333,  full_name: "student A",  score: 7,  class_id: 222}]

const res = dicList.flatMap(Object.entries)
res.forEach(([key,value]) => console.log(`key:${key} value:${value}`));
```

`flatMap()` doesnot work in all browsers so you use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and create nested `forEach()`

```js
var dicList = [{student_id: 334,  full_name: "student B",  score: 9,  class_id: 222}, {  student_id: 333,  full_name: "student A",  score: 7,  class_id: 222}]

const res = dicList.map(Object.entries)
res.forEach(a => a.forEach(([key,value]) => console.log(`key:${key} value:${value}`)));
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(f){
  return [].concat(...this.map(f))
}
```

You can also create polyfill for `flatMap()`

```
if(!Array.prototype.flatMap){
  Array.prototype.flatMap = function(f){
    return [].concat(...this.map(f))
  }
}
```

Comment: `Object.entries` is static, so it's safe to just `.flatMap(Object.entries)`

Comment: I'd suggest posting a polyfill for `flatMap` e.g. `[].concat(...this.map(f))` instead of nested loops.